# how to get selected value on button click in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How to get selected value in angulajs when clicked on the button, im using the following code please suggest me?

```
 <div class="form-inline">
       <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selectedTimeZone">
                <option data-ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in timeZoneData.countries" data-ng-bind="value.name"></option>
                 <option data-ng-repeat-end="" data-ng-repeat="tz in value.timezones" data-ng-bind="' - ' + tz"></option>
         </select>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <input id="btnAddTimeZone" type="button" value="Add Time Zone" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="populateTimeZone(selectedTimeZone)"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

in Controller--

```
$scope.populateTimeZone = function (world_timezones) {

};
```

Json data--

```
{
    "countries": {
     "US": {
          "id": "US",
          "name": "United States",
          "timezones": [
            "America/New_York",
            "America/Detroit",
             ]
        },
     "CA": {
          "id": "CA",
          "name": "Canada",
          "timezones": [
            "America/St_Johns",
            "America/Halifax",
           ]
        },
    "IN": {
          "id": "IN",
          "name": "India",
          "timezones": [
            "Asia/Kolkata"
          ]
        },
    }
    }
```

But im getting  empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the AngularJS docs:**

To bind the model to a non-string value, you can use one of the following strategies:

- the ngOptions directive (select)
- the ngValue directive, which allows arbitrary expressions to be option values (Example)
- model $parsers / $formatters to convert the string value (Example)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

**Option 1: Add `ng-value`**

All you need to do is add an `ng-value` to your options and it should work.  You also might want to add a `ng-disabled="true"` to your group headers so that it prevents the user from selecting "India" and not an actually timezone.

```
<option ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in timezones.countries" ng-bind="value.name" ng-disabled="true"></option>
<option ng-repeat-end="" ng-repeat="tz in value.timezones" ng-bind="' - ' + tz" ng-value="tz"></option>
```

Plunkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/l5H87H8k7Af5XIqH?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

**Option 2: `ng-options` with group by**

Here's a possible solution using `ng-options` on the select.  You can still achieve a groupBy functionality grouping your timezones by country name.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <label>Timezone: </label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedTimezone" ng-options="tz.timezone group by tz.country for tz in timezones"></select>
</form>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="populateTimeZone()">Add Timezone</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function MainCtrl($scope, MainService) {
    $scope.selectedTimezone = undefined;
    $scope.timezones = [];

    MainService.loadTimezones().then(function(timezoneData){
        $scope.timezones = Object.values(timezoneData.countries).flatMap(c => {
            return c.timezones.map(tz => {
                return {id: c.id, name: c.name, timezone: tz};
            });
        });
    });

    $scope.populateTimeZone = function(){
        console.log('selectedTimezone', $scope.selectedTimezone);
    };
}
```

Plunkr: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Y4AVNU9X6MUAzckz?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

Comment: Thank you so much.. but my json data is different than yours so I used above format.. I have uploaded json above.

Comment: I can make some slight adjustments based on the way the data is formatted, once you include the data just give me a moment. :D

Comment: Added json data.

Comment: Updated the answer and plunkr.   Basically just taking the timezone data and flattening it so that each item in the select is a different entry in the list.

Comment: I added a secondary option aswell.  Basically just adding `ng-value` to your existing solution.   I'm a little more fond of the second solution, as I feel its more accurate to use the `group by`, however, both are valid.   Enjoy :D

Comment: You explained well, thank you for your time. Have a good day sir.